# What is the constant value of D3DX_PI?

Tags: radians, d3dx

What is the `const` value of D3DX_PI?
Does it not really matter how i define, so for example i can just define it as

`#define D3DX_PI 3.14`

Or would it need to be more precie like:

`#define D3DX_PI 3.1415926535897932384626`

Comment: Why are you using legacy D3DX and D3DXmath instead of [DirectXMath](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/03/26/introducing-directxmath/) which provides the constant ``XM_PI``? Or you can use ``math.h`` and it's ``M_PI``. Unless your computation only needs two points of precision, ``3.14`` is unlikely to be accurate enough for most floating-point computations.